# Minimize the various norms given a set of linear equations.

Tags: least-squares

Given $Ax=b$, I know how to use least squares to minimize $\|Ax−b\|^2$. How do I minimize the 2-norm $(\|x\|^2)$ and the Frobenius norm of $x$? A is $3 \times 2$. B is $3 \times 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the problem $Ax = b$, let $A^\dagger$ be the [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $A$.  Setting $x$ as the vector
$$
z = A^\dagger b
$$
Will minimize both $\|Ax - b\|_2$ and $\|x\|_2$.